# Javascript(Ajax) vs PHP: Generating HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, php, html

Does generating html elements such as table rows with js through a ajax callback function really any slower than php(echo "< tr>< /tr>)?  The browser still has to render client-side the information into the table whether its done in php or js.

I couldn't find much information on this subject, so I wanted to get some opinions here.  Are there any arguments to not use js to generate elements dynamically from a ajax call?

Note: I originally forgot to mentioned that the table rows would be data from a database.

Answer (score 0):

In your case using ajax is time wasting because it should send request to server, and server should process it, then responding with the result, while using native JS (only javascript) is faster because the server is not included, and using direct print when page loading is fastest.

But if you need to work dynamic tables, you can work on JavaScript without AJAX call, I don't see any reason here to use AJAX for building HTML table.

Comment: With a proper API, I find it's better to request raw data with an ajax call, and build the DOM elements you require client-side. If you return pure HTML from the call then you prevent the same call from being made in other places leading to code duplication. See the wikipedia article on [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29#Disadvantages).

Answer (score 0):

Its perfectly fine to generate html elements using ajax call. There might arise occasion where you **HAVE** to return the **DYNAMICALLY** generated HTML elements.For this you cannot just print it client side since you need the info from the db.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have the info to be presented in a tabular form beforehand, meaning before the page is built, then you should use PHP.
2. If, the data is to be requested at runtime from the server, then AJAX should be used.
3. If you just want to built tables with no data (or repeating data which is already available on the page) then, using plain JavaScript is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an existing page with a table

```
  | A | A | A |
  | A | A | A |
```

Now you place an ajax-call reading some data from the server. If you want to replace the whole table it might be usefull to let php create the table, return it to the browser en let javascript replace the entire table.

If you only want the second row to change, you might want php to return an array with values and let javascript replace the cell-contents based on that response.

But one way or the other, you still have to go the circle browser => server => browser. So the few moments javascript takes to alter the page don't add too much time to that.